# Is there a way to get Range data type into mysql database using Springboot and HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, spring-boot

I am doing a project and am have created a html element that allows people to select a capacity (on a slider). I have done this with the help of JavaScript. However when on the html page, users can select their capacity but it doesnt convert into the database. Instead it stays at 0. Whereas if I change the data type to int it works but without the JavaScript Slider element. Also im new to this site so please bear with me.   In other words do I need to convert it to int, if yes how do i do this?

------------------HTML

```
 <div class="capacity"> 
             <input type="number" min="10" max="100" value="55"
                             class="myslider" id="Capacity"> 
           <div class="valid-feedback">WELL DONE</div>
           <div class="invalid-feedback">ADD A CAPACITY !</div>
             <p>Persons: <span id="capacityOfEvent"></span></p>
```

--------------------------- Spring boot Java File

```
  @Column(name = "capacity", nullable = false, length = 55)
    private int Capacity;
    
    
    public int getCapacity() {
        return Capacity;
    }
    
    public void setCapacity(int Capacity) {
        this.Capacity =Capacity;
    }
```

---------------------------------JavaScript

```
//Capacity of people 
var capacitySlider = document.getElementById("Capacity"); 
var output = document.getElementById("capacityOfEvent"); 
output.innerHTML =capacitySlider.value;  
capacitySlider.oninput = function() { 
  output.innerHTML = this.value; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using slider on your JavaScript side but is it affecting your backend. Are you calling your server each time your slider value gets changed I don't see any AJAX call being made in your code. So if you want your database value to get changed you have to call your backend every time your slider value gets changed. You can do that using rest controllers at your server side spring-boot and doing AJAX calls from client to your backend.(maybe using some library like axios or XMLHttpRequest).

p.s. if you provide more details I'll edit my answer but for now I can only tell you this much from your code. Also please include your controller code.